# unable to start up django app with runsslserver

Tags: django, python-3.x, ssl-certificate

I am completely new to Django/python so excuse any wrong vocabulary.

I have a Django based application that has been running perfectly on the HTTP protocol in an Ubuntu server. (Django is used both as App server and webserver here) I was asked to migrate the application from HTTP to the HTTPS protocol.

I have performed the below steps in the server.

Installed the following packages:

```
django-extensions, django-secure, and django-sslserver
```

Added `'sslserver'` in setting.py under INSTALLED_APPS

Placed certificate and key in `/etc/ssl/certs/ and /etc/ssl/private` respectively

Start-up application with the command:

```
python3 manage.py runsslserver --certificate /etc/ssl/certs/my.cer --key /etc/ssl/private/my.key 172.31.83.127:8081 --configuration=uat
```

I have updated the CLB as below: -

```
[CLB Listener][1]


[CLB Health Check][2]
```

**Now, when I run the command in the server I am getting below errors: -**

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
self._write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
result = self.stdout.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 593, in write
return self._sock.send(b)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 861, in send
return self._sslobj.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 586, in write
return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1848)
[13/Jan/2020 17:54:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Exception happened during processing of request from ('172.31.5.104', 33784)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 279, in write
self._write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 453, in _write
result = self.stdout.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 593, in write
return self._sock.send(b)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 861, in send
return self._sslobj.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 586, in write
return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1848)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
self.handle_error()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
super().handle_error()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
self.finish_response()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 625, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in init
self.handle()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
super().close()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 36, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any help here would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How did you get your certificate?

Comment: I got it from the client, they are already using the same certificates in other applications as well.

Comment: can anyone help here, I am really stuck with no solutions.